# Z-Index Behaving Differently in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, z-index

I've been working on a 3D piece http://jsbin.com/vihoye/3/edit?html,output

It's perfect with exception to my final hurdle.  For some reason the Z-index is behaving differently in Chrome and Safari.  There are 2 things going wrong here but both are positioning issues.

ISSUE #1

The solar system is controlled by the menu to the lower right.  When you click on say "Life Skills" info dialogue pops up over the planet.  In FireFox when you mouse over the dialogue it triggers a pop-up as it should.  However in Chrome and Safari I can't trigger the mouseover event.

ISSUE #2

In FireFox, once the mouseover event is triggered the popup appears on top of the solar system as it should.  However, in Chrome and Safari the planets rotate thru the pop-up.

I can't figure out if it is the position property or if it is the rotateY that is causing the problem.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Code or does not happen!

Comment: Hi @Justinas.  I inserted the link to the JSBin because the code is too long to post in here.  I was pretty sure I shared both the HTML and output panel in the bin.  Since I am not sure where the problem is I didn't want to dismantle to code and try to insert it inline here.  Can you not see the code in the bin?

Comment: Generated the link share again http://jsbin.com/vihoye/3/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here is my solution [DEMO JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tapawi/1/edit). It is working perfectly in Chrome but in Safari the planets rotate thru the pop-up still. More debugging and it may be fixable but it is not that bad of an anomaly.

I just changed this one CSS ID accordingly:

```
#galaxy {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    perspective: 4000;
    -webkit-perspective; 4000;
}
```

Comment: thank you!  Definitely works in Chrome.  We're going to keep looking to the answer for Safari.  We can't leave it that way.

Comment: Thanks for recognizing me that was a lot of trial and error figuring that out. I honestly think you will be hard pressed to fix that if at all but I will try and take another look sometime today.

Comment: Thank you again for your efforts!  The actual planets would be fine.  The real problem is the top portion of the sun.  It obscures the text slide show.

Comment: BTW if you ever need any custom artwork done for a project we're happy to return the favor.